# How to efficiently use Pool.starmap when the function requires a large data structure as an argument?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing, pool, kdtree

#### Background:

I took over some code in a notebook that made heavy use of global variables which on the one hand made it easy to use `Pool.imap`, but on the other hand makes it difficult to read, debug and move out of a jupyter notebook into the real world:

This method simply calls another method `query_rec` to perform a KNN search around the given point. Note that `points_adjusted` and `times` are defined outside of the function. `query_rec` uses a  `KDTree` defined outside of its scope:

```
def get_neighbors(i):
    point = points_adjusted[i] + (times[i],)
    temp = query_rec(point, INPUT_EVENT_COUNT, 2)
    return temp

def query_rec(point, k, rk):
    # KNN SEARCH... TOO MUCH CODE AND DOESNT MATTER FOR THE QUESTION

sorted_training_data = [t for t in pool.imap(get_neighbors, np.arange(num_points) if t]
```

#### What I want to achieve:

I want to refactor `get_neighbors` and `query_rec` to not use global variables but still be able to use multi-processing.

#### What I tried Part 1:

I refactored the above functions so that they would take as arguments the global variables:

```
def get_neighbors(points, tree, i, k=INPUT_EVENT_COUNT):
    point = points[i]
    temp = query_rec(point, tree, k, 2)
    return temp
```

Following this up, I have to make an iterable containing all the arguments I want to pass to my newly refactored function:

```
pool = Pool(NUM_WORKERS)
args = zip([points] * num_points, [training_tree] * num_points, np.arange(num_points))
sorted_training_data = [t for t in pool.starmap(get_neighbors, args) if t]
```

**The Problem with my solution:**
There are about 3 million points in `points`, and I am making 3 million copies of the KDTree `training_tree`. This seems really bad to me.

#### What I Tried part 2:

I tried encapsulating the functionality I wanted in a new data structure like so:

```
class TimeTree:
    """
    A data structure combining a KDTree and a uniform gridspace of points for efficeient NN searches.
    """
    def __init__(self, kdtree, grid_points):
        """
        :param kdtree: a KDTree containing event data points in the form (lat, lng, time)
        :param grid_points: A uniform gridspace of (lat, lng, time) points 
        """
        self.tree = kdtree
        self.points = grid_points
        self.size = len(grid_points)
        
    def search(self, idx, k, rk=2):
        """
        A function designed to be used with a multiprocess.pool to perform a global KNN search
        of all points in the ``self.points`` list.
        :param idx: The index of the point to search around.
        :param k: The number of neighbors to search for.
        :param rk: A recursive constant for extended search capabilites.
        """
        return query_rec(self.points[idx], self.tree, k, rk)
```

And then created a helper function to generate the data:

```
def generate_data(k, t, workers=NUM_WORKERS):
    args = zip(np.arange(t.size), [k] * t.size)
    with Pool(workers) as p:
        data = [d for d in tqdm(p.starmap(t.search, args), total=t.size) if d]
    return data
```

I read this was a solution to `Pool` objects having pickle problems when using `Pool.map`. I believe this might work, except I found yet another global variable inside of the `query_rec` definition that I had not noticed before. This may be a solution, and I will update later.

#### The Question:

How do I efficiently use multi-processing on a function that takes large data structures as arguments?

Comment: I assume you are doing this on a forking system like linux/mac and not windows so that the child processes have a view of parent memory at the time they are created?

Comment: @tdelaney I'm doing it on a bit of both. I'm using linux on the cloud when I have to, but doing as much as I can on my personal laptop to save money when I can.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I would suggest you to use a partial module from functools, it helped me alot:

```
from functools import partial

def f(x, y, a, b, c, d):
  # important: abcd variables should be at the right
  return x + y + a + b + c + d
    
f_of_x = partial(f, a=5, b=10, c=15, d=20)
```

This **f_of_x** you can pass to the Pool *starmap(f_of_x, zip(X, Y))*.

Also you can import all the values for *abcd* from another file with constants. But be careful: Pool with imported global variables will not update nor change them in the original file if it is executed (it works in a weird way), also it will not pickle lambdas.

Actually there are so many problems you can face related to Pool and other multiprocessing stuff in Python, and sometimes it is hard to find an answer. Some of them could be found by different or related Google queries, good luck :)